Can't use Array.prototype.includes() to match an enum with type
I can't use includes method with an array of enum and a type. Both of them contain same values. Here is an example code:
type TypeStatus = "todo" | "doing" | "done";

enum EnumStatus {
    Todo = "todo",
    Doing = "doing",
    Done = "done"
}

function test(myStatus: TypeStatus) {
    [EnumStatus.Todo, EnumStatus.Doing].includes(myStatus)
}

I am getting the following error from Typescript:

Argument of type 'TypeStatus' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EnumStatus'.
Type '"todo"' is not assignable to type 'EnumStatus'.(2345)


Why do you want to compare two different types? It looks like you actually want function test(myStatus: EnumStatus)

The conventional way to do this is to widen the array before doing includes, such as shown in this playground link. I'll find relevant duplicates.

You can assert myStatus as EnumStatus to align the types:
function test(myStatus: TypeStatus) {
    return [EnumStatus.Todo, EnumStatus.Doing].includes(myStatus as EnumStatus);
}

This approach informs TypeScript that myStatus can be treated as an EnumStatus value.
